# Email Body Format Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

i had a problem in format in email. I want to have a new line..

here's the format in email..

```
Name: sdds Phone: 343434 Fax: 3434 Email: valencia_arman@yahoo.com Address: dsds Remarks: dsds Giftwrap: Yes Giftwrap Instructions: sdds Details: PEOPLE OF THE BIBLE(SCPOTB-8101-05) 1 x Php 275.00 = Php 275.00 Total: Php275.00
```

here's my C# code..

```
mail.Body = "Name: " + newInfo.ContactPerson + Environment.NewLine
                                + "Phone: " + newInfo.Phone + Environment.NewLine
                                + "Fax: " + newInfo.Fax + Environment.NewLine
                                + "Email: " + newInfo.Email + Environment.NewLine
                                + "Address: " + newInfo.Address + Environment.NewLine
                                + "Remarks: " + newInfo.Notes + Environment.NewLine
                                + "Giftwrap: " + rbGiftWrap.SelectedValue + Environment.NewLine
                                + "Giftwrap Instructions: " + newInfo.Instructions + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine
                                + "Details: " + Environment.NewLine
                                + mailDetails;
```

Comment: I'm still learning but wouldn't it be better to use String Builder to create this string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sending it in HTML, make sure you set the format.

```
mail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
```

And then you can use `<br/>` should you want to.

UPDATE:

Try this as an alternative:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
```

...

```
MailMessage myMail;
myMail = new MailMessage();
myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

Comment: So you've set the mail type as html and you're adding <br/> to end of each item instead of Environment.NewLine? How are you viewing the email?

Comment: i viewed it on my mail.. i tried your code above and i received problem in using mail.bodyformat = mailformat.html..

Comment: I've added some changes. Which .Net framework are you using? My fragment uses 4.0.

Comment: @SilverFang - if you are going to use HTML, you may want to HtmlEncode fields like "Remarks", which may contain characters which have special meaning in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this...

We create seperate email templates (e.g. EmailTemplate.htm), it includes the message to be sent. You will have no problems for new line in message.

Then this is our Code behind:

```
private void SendEmail()
{
   string emailPath = "../EmailTemplate.htm"; //Define your template path here
   string emailBody = string.Empty;

   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(emailPath);

   emailBody = sr.ReadToEnd();
   sr.Close();
   sr.Dispose();

   //Send Email; you can refactor this out
   MailMessage message = new MailMessage();

   MailAddress address = new MailAddress("sender@domain.com", "display name");

   message.From = address;
   message.To.Add("to@domain.com");
   message.Subject = "Your Subject";
   message.IsBodyHtml = true; //defines that your email is in Html form
   message.Body = emailBody;

   //smtp is defined in web.config
   SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

   try
   {
      smtp.Send(message);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      //catch errors here...
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, too late for me. Haha! :D

Answer (score 0):

Did you try "+\n" instead of Environment.NewLine?